# I can't seem to get pytest in flask and sqlalchemy to run in my pytesting_create_app function. Anyone know how to solve this? More details below

Tags: python, flask, pytest, flask-sqlalchemy

Here is the error.

```
E       RuntimeError: No application found. Either work inside a view function or push an application context. See http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/contexts/.
```

Basically the error boils down to https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/contexts/
. I added the function def my_function(): from the the flask link. It does not seem to work. I named the function a different name in the code below. It is called def context. I also noticed that I created the function but I have no idea where to call the function. I can add all the code my entire github if needed also.

Here is the relevant code for pytesting. I did not include imports.

**conftest.py**

```
@pytest.fixture() 
def new_user():
    plaintext_password = 'pojkp[kjpj[pj'
    hashed_password = bcrypt.hashpw(plaintext_password.encode('utf-8'), bcrypt.gensalt())  
    current_user = User(username='fkpr[kfkuh', hashed_password=hashed_password, email=os.environ['TESTING_EMAIL_USERNAME'],
    confirmation_email=False)
    return current_user

db = SQLAlchemy()

login_manager = LoginManager()

login_manager.login_message_category = 'Login is required'


login_manager.login_view = 'login' 


csrf = CSRFProtect()

email = RedMail()


@pytest.fixture() 
def pytesting_create_app(config_obj=Pytest_Config):     
app = Flask(name)
    app.config.from_object(config_obj)
    
    app.debug = True
    db.init_app(app)
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    email.init_app(app) 
    db.create_all()
    
    yield app 

def context(new_user, pytesting_create_app):
    with pytesting_create_app.app_context():
        user = db.User(new_user)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()



@pytest.fixture()
def init_database(new_user):
  
    db.create_all()
    db.session.add(new_user)
    db.session.commit()
    yield 
    db.drop_all()
```

I have 2 different configurations in the file below but I only posted the relevant one.

**config.py**

```
class Test_Config: 
    DEBUG = True
    # Is the same value as ['DEBUG'] =  
    EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
    EMAIL_PORT = '0' 
    Mail_DEBUG = True  
    # for pytest
    TESTING = True     
    # same value ['TESTING'] =. If you are testing your app if you don't want to send emails make it True?
    MAIL_SUPRESS_SEND = True  
    # When False this disables wtf forms. This useful for pytests that are POST request.
    WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = False 
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False   
    # I get 'DATABASE_URI' sqlite:///app.db or I get os.path.join(basedir, 'app.db') gives me app.db route
    # "\" is used as newline 
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URI') or \
    'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'app.db')
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and trim the code down to a [mcve], without external links.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to fix the error in the code above? I would really appreciate an answer